# Display problems after upgrading to 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, display

I have a Dell Inspiron 7537 laptop which was running Ubuntu 14.04LTS until this weekend. I've just updated to 16.04LTS (hoping that the update might fix the awful WiFi performance and frequent touchpad failures).
Since the update the built-in screen has become flickery, as though the refresh rate has dropped. I also see a lot of flashes of white along the bottom edge of the screen.
Has anyone else seen this with 16.04, and is there a solution?
At the moment I'm considering doing a fresh install of 14.04, it's that bad.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you install any specific drivers while running 14.04 for display?

Comment: No, it was an out-of-the-box install that I never had to fine-tune.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "Force" GPU acceleration at you Chrome, for the flickering issue. Plus a fresh install will resolve several issues. However, battery indicator or a few more issues might also continue. However, the WiFi issues is resolved while in 14.04 you should force the WiFi card in powersaver-mode Off mode.